# How to change output layout of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

Below is my current program

```
int [] balls = {13, 13, 13}

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
    System.out.println("Remaining balls: " + (i + 1) + " : " + bags[i]);
}
```

The output looks like this;

```
Remaining balls: 13
Remaining balls: 13
Remaining balls: 13
```

However, I wish for the output to look like this:

```
Remaining balls: 13, 13, 13
```

How would I go about this?

I haven't tried many things yet as I'm just starting out.

Comment: Try Arrays.toString(balls) from the java.util.Arrays package

Comment: Split it into 3 prints: The initial part, then a loop over the values then the newline outside of the loop

Comment: I can't beleave that the output fits to the code. I expect two colons in every line. Please add a [mcve], so that we can run the code

Answer (score -2):

```
System.out.println(..)
```

always adds a new line. That's coded into the method name print*ln*

There is also pendants that do not add the extra line add the end of the output:

```
System.out.print(..)
```